# Adding Build Target in Atom Editor

Tags: latex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom as a latex editor, with packages build, language-latex, and latextools installed. Now when I try and build using Ctrl-Alt-B, the latex file compiles and gives a pdf output, but when I build using f9, an error is thrown that says:

```
No eligible build target.

No configuration to build this project exists.
```

Also, when I press f7 to show the build targets, it says "no targets found."

Could someone enlighten me as to what I'm missing in the setup for latex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `build` package is an unopinionated base package that requires the installation of separate [service providers](https://atombuild.github.io/). In the case of LaTeX, you likely want to use [`build-latex`](https://atom.io/packages/build-latex).

Comment: I've installed the `build-latex` package, but still encounter the same problem. Is there anything else I must change/install?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but when I opened a different project, it works now. I suspect that I had to restart atom in order for the changes to take effect. Thanks!

Comment: Another pitfall: the `build` package only works with projects, not single files

Answer (score 0):

you need a base branch or a template theme to include hot keys for your specific thread or template...

I recommend using sphinx

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/contents.html

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/py-modindex.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)